# Regarding Heroku Postgres limit of 20 connections, if I close pgadmin will I have to waste another connection?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, pgadmin, heroku-postgres

I connected to my team's Heroku Postgres database through pgAdmin 4, using up 1 out of the 20 connections limit. If I stop the pgAdmin server, will I have to reconnect later when I need it and waste another connection? I'm new to backend and just an intern so I don't want to mess anything up. Thanks for the help

Comment: Connections are only occupied so long as the process is running.

Comment: Isn't the connection limit very small then

Comment: That's a pretty tight connection limit, but it should be enough for a small app to survive. You'll just need to be careful and not ask for too many in a connection pool.